# Upgrading from Angular 2 to Angular 7, cannot bind [x] since it isn't a property of [y]

Tags: angular, inheritance, angular7

**Solution:**
I forgot to change the HTML on the place where the parent was showing the child. The selector of all components have changed in the conversion. I forgot to check that, so thanks for everyone who pointed to the HTML!

I'm upgrading an Angular 2 project to Angular 7 and I'm running into an error that I cannot solve with answers from google.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Can't bind to 'xClass' since it isn't a known property of 'yComponent'.
1. If 'yComponent' is an Angular component and it has 'xClass' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

I've found two answers on google. One is that it only happens in production build, but I'm not working in production build yet (as far as I know).
The other is to add the component to the `declarations` in the app module. I have added it and made sure that it was on the top of the list (as I read that the order of the declarations is also important).

I have tried adding the class to the declarations, but that also gives a compile error.

How can I 'import' the class in the component?

Here is the (relevant) code from the app module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { yComponent } from './song-detail/song-detail.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    yComponent,
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
    ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

xClass:

```
export class XClass {
    constructor
    (
        public name: string,
        public search_name: string,
        public source: string,
        public source_type: string,
        public source_name: string,
    )
    {}
}
```

yComponent:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { XClass } from '../model/xClass';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-y-component',
  template: `
  <h2>{{ class.name }}</h2>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./y-component.css']
})
export class yComponent {

  @Input() class:Class;

}
```

**Edit:**
I made a typo here. I had `@Input() xClass:XClass`.

Comment: `@Input() class:Class;` is this correct?

Comment: can you put html part as well?

Comment: class should be of type XClass; `  @Input() class:XClass;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to have input `xClass` meanwhile declaring input `class`.

The input should be used next way
`@Input() propery: interface = initialValue`

Where `property` is name which you will use later like `<my-awesome-component [propery]="2"></my-awesome-component>`

Meaning it should be the same as you specify on component in `[]` or standalone when passing just a string.

Interface should be provided in order to avoid simple mistakes.

And `initialValue` you may use if you wish to have customizable property with default value.

If you don't need any initial values you are free to use `@Input() propery: interface`, or even `@Input() propery` if you don't care about types

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful while declaring @Input property in component.
Make sure the object provided as input to component selector in HTML, is same as what is expected in component declaration.

Ex:

```
<my-component [additionalDataInput]="myObjectFromParentComponent"></my-component>
```

and in component:

```
export class MyComponent {
@Input() additionalDataInput: TypeOfMyObjectFromParentComponent; // has to be same type
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Input() class:Class;
```

should be

```
@Input() xClass:XClass;
```

alternatively, if you dont want to change your variable name, you can use

```
@Input("xClass") class:Class;
```